# Key exist in complexe array

Tags: php, arrays, post

I would like to test if the key of an associative array exist in my `$_POST`.

my $_POST is like that:

```
$_POST["balle"]["x"] = 5;
$_POST["balle"]["y"] = 5;
$_POST["balle"]["z"] = 5;
```

or like that by example:

```
$_POST["p1"][1]["vit"] = 7;
$_POST["p1"][1]["angle"] = 32;
$_POST["p2"][2]["vit"] = 17;
$_POST["p2"][2]["angle"] = 2;
```

the values don't matter but I must check how are my `$_POST` keys.
I don't understand how i can test recursivly that because the `$_POST` can change and have differents forms.

I have try this:

```
function Check_post($new, $arr)
{
    echo "Init<br/>";
    $res = true;
    if (is_array($new))
    {
        foreach ($new as $key => $value)
        {
            if (!in_array($key, $arr))
            {
                echo "Fail $key";
                print_r($arr);
                return (false);
            }
            $res = $res & Check_post($new[$key], $arr[$key]);
        }
    }
    else
        $res = in_array($new, $arr);
    echo "MY RESULT";
    var_dump($res);
    return ($res);
}

$b = array();
$b["balle"] = array("x", "y", "z");

$post = array();
$post["balle"] = array();
$post["balle"]["x"] = 50;
$post["balle"]["y"] = 50;
$post["balle"]["z"] = 50;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($b);
echo "</pre><pre>";
print_r($post);
echo "</pre>";
Check_post($b, $post);
```

but i got `"Fail balle"`. my `$post` variable is to simulate the real `$_POST` and for make it easier to test.

EDIT:
The function should work like that:
1) test if "balle" exist in $post
2) "balle" exist so recursive call
3) test if "x" exist in `$post["balle"](recursive)`
4) test if "y" exist in `$post["balle"](recursive)`
5) test if "z" exist in `$post["balle"](recursive)`
6) all existe so $res = true

Comment: What will be your search term ?

Comment: normaly the $balle array match with my $post variable because each key in $post exist in $balle. I just want to give a boolean for if it's match or not.

Comment: `...the $_POST can change and have differents forms.` I don't quite understand what are you trying to say. By different forms do you mean different size? Index names? Index number? It's unclear what are you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That refers to the 2 example of the $_POST that I show bellow.

Comment: @QuentinJadeau check my answer. i think it will solve your porblem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I finaly editet the whole function:

```
function Check_post($needle, $haystack)
{
    if(is_array($needle)){
        foreach ($needle as $key => $element){

            $result = true;

            if($result = (array_key_exists($key, $haystack) || array_key_exists($element, $haystack))){

                $key = (isset($haystack[$key]) ? $key : $element);
                if(is_array($haystack[$key]))
                    $result = Check_post($element, $haystack[$key]);

            }
            if(!$result){
                return false;
            }

        }
        return $result;
    }else {
        return array_key_exists($needle, $haystack);
    }

}
```

Now it should work as you want it

Example:

```
$_POST["balle"]["x"] = 5;
$_POST["balle"]["y"] = 5;
$_POST["balle"]["z"] = 5;

$b = array();
$b["balle"] = array("x", "y", "z");

var_dump(Check_post($b, $_POST));  //returns true

$b["balle"] = array("x", "y", "z", "b");

var_dump(Check_post($b, $_POST));  //returns false
```

Comment: No because my needle is an array.

Comment: @QuentinJadeau, must every key exists in the array?

Comment: Yes, that must do as it is in the EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

The `in_array` function you're using checks if `$key` is contained in `$arr` as a **value**. If I got you right, you want to check if there is the same **key** in `$arr` instead. Use `array_key_exists($key, $arr)` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$_POST["p1"][1]["vit"] = 7;
$_POST["p1"][1]["angle"] = 32;
$_POST["p2"][2]["vit"] = 17;
$_POST["p2"][2]["angle"] = 2;

$needle = "2";

$samp = Check_post($_POST,$needle);

echo $samp;

function Check_post($array,$needle)
{
    if(is_array($array))
    {

        foreach($array as $key=>$value)
        {

            if($key == $needle)
            {
                echo $key." key exists ";
            }
            else
            {
                if(is_array($value))
                {
                    check_post($value,$needle);
                }
            }


        }

    }

}
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/UI7of)

Comment: That works but the realy thing i want to do is to have $needle as an array of my required key for $_POST

Comment: @QuentinJadeau what will be the dimension of the array ?

Comment: the $needle would be an associate array so that can change. In my example $b is like your $needle.